# Matplotlib graph expand the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I  have the following [image: graph].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()


x_values = [2**6,2**7,2**8,2**9,2**10,2**12]
y_values_ST = [7.3,15,29,58,117,468]     
y_values_S3 = [2.3,4.6,9.1,19,39,156]     
xticks=['2^6','2^7','2^8','2^9','2^10','2^12']

plt.plot(x_values, y_values_ST,'-gv')
plt.plot(x_values, y_values_S3,'-r+')
plt.legend(['ST','S^3'], loc='upper left')
plt.xticks(x_values,xticks)

fig.suptitle('Encrypted Query Size Overhead')
plt.xlabel('Query size')
plt.ylabel('Size in KB')
plt.grid()
fig.savefig('token_size_plot.pdf')
plt.show()
```

1)How i can delete the last gap as shown after 2^12?
2)How i can spread more the values in the x axis such that the first two values are not overlapped?

Answer (score 3):

> 1)How i can delete the last gap as shown after 2^12?

Set the limits explicitly, e.g.:

```
plt.xlim(2**5.8, 2**12.2)
```

> 2)How i can spread more the values in the x axis such that the first two values are not overlapped?

You seem to want a log plot. Use `pyplot.semilog()`, or set the log scale on the x-axis (base 2 seems appropriate in your case):

```
plt.xscale('log', basex=2)
```

Note that in this case you don't even have to set the `2^*` ticks manually, they will be created this way automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Using `autoscale`, specify the axes, or alternately you can use `plt.axis('tight')` for both the axes. 2.Using log scaled x-axis. Code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

x_values = [2**6,2**7,2**8,2**9,2**10,2**12]
y_values_ST = [7.3,15,29,58,117,468]
y_values_S3 = [2.3,4.6,9.1,19,39,156]
xticks=['2^6','2^7','2^8','2^9','2^10','2^12']

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.plot(x_values, y_values_ST,'-gv')
plt.plot(x_values, y_values_S3,'-r+')
plt.legend(['ST','S^3'], loc='upper left')
plt.xticks(x_values,xticks)

fig.suptitle('Encrypted Query Size Overhead')
plt.xlabel('Query size')
plt.ylabel('Size in KB')

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)#plt.axis('tight')
plt.grid()
fig.savefig('token_size_plot.pdf')
plt.show()
```